# Characterization of Linear Operators by Spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, spectral-theory

For a (finite dimensional) complex vector space $V$, the Spectral Theorem tells us that for every normal operator $T$ there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T.$ Similarly, for a real vector space $V$, the Spectral Theorem tells us that for every self adjoint operator $T$ there is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T.$

In other words;

Complex vector space: Normal operator $\implies$ existence of an orthonormal eigenvector basis.

Real vector space: Self adjoint operator $\implies$ existence of an orthonormal eigenvector basis.

> What if we drop the restriction that the basis needs to be
> orthonormal?

Is it the case that for *every* operator $T$ there is a basis of of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$, though now this basis need not be orthonormal? Or is there a more general class of operators for which this holds, but it does not necessarily hold for every operator?

In other words;

Complex vector space: Property A $\implies$ existence of an eigenvector basis.

Real vector space: Property B $\implies$ existence of an eigenvector basis.

What are properties A and B?

Comment: sadly, not. The class of matrix for which it holds are called "diagonalizable", and can be characterized by totally factorizable minimal polynomials

Comment: @Exodd So when the term "diagonalizable" is used the speaker does not necessarily mean "diagonalizable with respect to an orthonormal basis/unitary transformation"? What does it mean for the minimal polynomial to be totally factorizable?

Comment: Recall that a linear operator $T$ on a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial of $T$ factors into distinct linear factors. Every linear operator $T$ over a finite-dimensional complex vector space can be written as an upper triangular matrix with respect to some basis because the minimal polynomial of $T$ factors into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed, so it suffices to check that no linear factor is repeated.

Comment: In general, a matrix $A\in K^{n\times n}$ is diagonalizable if there exists an invertible matrix $M$ such that $A = MDM^{-1}$ where $D\in K^{n\times n}$ is a diagonal matrix. In other words, a matrix is diagonalizable when there exists a base change that makes it diagonal.

When dealing with self-adjoint operators, the base changes are always chosen orthogonal, in order to preserve the self-adjoint-ness. Since in most applied sciences (physics, chemistry, etc.) in the 90% of cases you work only with self-adjoint operators, it is no wonder that you think all the base changes are orthogonal.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $ and try to convince yourself that it is not diagonalizable.

You might also be interested in the Jordan normal form. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form

Comment: I am convinced that is not diagonalizable. So my question now would be: what is the class of operators which are diagonalizable? Do they have any interesting properties from the operator point of view? (For example, the normal operators are diagonalizable by a unitary transformation, and they have the interesting property $T^* T = TT^*$).

Comment: Well the characteristic polynomial is $x^2$.